# How to Load Remote Data in Bootstrap 3 accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is my attempt
http://laravel.io/bin/6LQ3v

The routes and jquery are loading correctly I have a modal loading remote data on the page.
How can I utilize it to load data inside the collapsed accordion?

Comment: please write the code you've attempted in this post.

Comment: btw the code is in the paste bin link,

Comment: I understand that. But when posting a question in stackoverflow you need to have the code in the post. The link will one day be broken and if someone else will look for an question/answer similar to this he/she will not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by wrapping the remote result in a new div id
btw the code is in the paste bin link,

here is the solution:
http://laravel.io/bin/nQvMl